# Chrome kills response when trying to stream OGG files

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, google-chrome

I have a Node JS server which streams (appends) OGG files to multiple HTTP responses with HTML5 audio on the other end. Everything is working nicely in Firefox, however Chrome seems to kill the response after the first OGG file has been written (but not Mp3 strangely).

Here is a snippet of the current code:

```
res.writeHead(200, {
    "Content-Type": "audio/ogg",
    'Pragma': 'no-cache',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, private, no-store, must-revalidate, max-stale=0, post-check=0, pre-check=0',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked',
});

res.write(audioData);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by `the first OGG`?

Comment: I meant it plays the entirety of the first file sent from the server, and then cuts the response without playing the next.

Comment: Oh, so you mean you are concatenating the ogg files by writing them to the stream one at a time?

Comment: Yep. Unfortunately it looks like an ongoing issue with Chrome: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=175281

Comment: I have the same issue with ogg/opus, have you managed to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately for you, the bug has been marked as :

> Labels: StaleClosed Status: WontFix

by Chrome devs. You could always reopen the ticket and harass them :)

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=175281